# How to get unique emails in a two column list where values can have two (or more!) separate values

Tags: python, performance, tuples, pandas-groupby, unique

This is a repost of a similar question I asked a few weeks back and I think I am able to do this but at significant (read: untenable) cost to my performance. There was a heroic poster at there who helped me somewhat and I am reposting at his/her direction. My code:

```
Donors = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\am\Desktop\email parsing\Q1 2021\Donors Q1 2021 R12.csv",
                        usecols=["Email Address"], na_values= True)
Activists = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\am\Desktop\email parsing\Q1 2021\Activists Q1 2021 R12.csv",
                        usecols=["Email"], na_filter= True)
Low_Level_Activists = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\am\Desktop\email parsing\Q1 2021\Low Level Activists Q1 2021 R12.csv",
                        usecols=["Email"], na_filter= True)
Ambassadors = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\am\Desktop\email parsing\Q1 2021\Student Ambassadors Q1 2021.csv",
                        usecols=["Email Address"], na_filter= True)
Volunteers = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\am\Desktop\email parsing\Q1 2021\Volunteers Q1 2021 R12.csv",
                        usecols=["Email Address"], na_filter= True)

Donors['Value'] = "Donors"
Activists['Value'] = "Activists"
Low_Level_Activists['Value'] = "Low_Level_Activists"
Ambassadors['Value'] = "Ambassadors"
Volunteers['Value'] = "Volunteers"
Advocates['Value'] = 'Followers'

S1= pd.concat([Donors,Activists,Low_Level_Activists,Ambassadors,Volunteers,Advocates], ignore_index= True)
S1['Handle'] = S1['Email Address'].where(S1['Email Address'].notnull(), S1['Email'])
S1= S1.drop(['Email','Email Address'], axis = 1)
print(S1['Handle'].count()) #checks full count
```

Now here is the difficult part - an email address can be a Donor and Activist, Activist and Volunteer, all five Values and so on but mostly it's one email one value. **I need to get a Dataframe (or list or dictionary) where I capture a unique email address in it's earliest import class. If an email is a donor and a volunteer than it's a donor. If it's an Activist and a Low Level Activist then Activist and so on.**

I am looking for output that has each Value group along with the unique count of emails. This code:

```
pd.Series({value: len(group.Handle.unique()) for value, group in S1.groupby('Value')})
```

does the trick (h/t Jan W.) but it does not condense the email counts based on the earliest "value." Help would be greatly appreciated as I have been at this for many days. There are 1,700 instances in this set where a email exists in two or more places among 167,000 email addresses. I can't seem to get around using a for loop then switching back to pandas series etc. etc. If I can get efficient code to figure this out again would be greatly appreciated!

Sample data (again h/t Jan W):

```
fa = pd.DataFrame([['paul@mail.com', 'Donors'], ['max@mail.com', 'Donors']], columns=['Handle', 'Value'])
fb = pd.DataFrame([['paul@mail.com', 'Activists'], ['annie@mail.com', 'Activists']], columns=['Handle', 'Value'])
S1 = pd.concat([fa, fb])
```

Comment: When you say "its earliest import class", do you mean the first one by lexicographic order? Or in the order of the DataFrame?

Comment: The first one in lexicographic order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining pandas `groupby` and `sort_values` methods will allow to run everything quite fast. The snippet below is an example implementation.

First generate ~100K rows of random data (this is a bit twisted but not relevant to your actual problem):

```py
from itertools import combinations
import string

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


emails = [
    f"{''.join(chars)}@{domain}"
    for chars in combinations(string.ascii_lowercase, 4)
    for domain in ["example.com", "domain.org"]
]
roles = [
    "Donors",
    "Activists",
    "Low_Level_Activists",
    "Ambassadors",
    "Ambassadors",
    "Ambassadors",
]

n = 100_000

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Handle": np.random.choice(emails, size=n),
        "Value": np.random.choice(roles, size=n),
    }
).drop_duplicates()
```

Now `df` looks like:

```py
                 Handle                Value
0       agnt@domain.org          Ambassadors
1       fmox@domain.org  Low_Level_Activists
2       cmny@domain.org  Low_Level_Activists
3       fgpq@domain.org          Ambassadors
4      hikw@example.com  Low_Level_Activists
...                 ...                  ...
99993   ejvz@domain.org            Activists
99994   aehr@domain.org          Ambassadors
99995  efjy@example.com          Ambassadors
99997  aeow@example.com          Ambassadors
99999   aetw@domain.org               Donors

[62609 rows x 2 columns]
```

Then fetch for each email the first role it belongs to:

```py
df = df.sort_values("Value").groupby("Handle", as_index=False)["Value"].first()
```

```py
                 Handle        Value
0       abcd@domain.org    Activists
1      abcd@example.com       Donors
2       abce@domain.org  Ambassadors
3      abce@example.com    Activists
4       abcf@domain.org  Ambassadors
...                 ...          ...
28848  vwyz@example.com    Activists
28849   vxyz@domain.org  Ambassadors
28850  vxyz@example.com  Ambassadors
28851   wxyz@domain.org  Ambassadors
28852  wxyz@example.com    Activists
[28853 rows x 2 columns]
```

And finally count the number of emails per role:

```py
df = df.groupby("Value")["Handle"].nunique()
```

```py
Value
Activists              12765
Ambassadors            13987
Donors                  1374
Low_Level_Activists      727
Name: Handle, dtype: int64
```

Once `df` is defined, the two calculations above only run in ~100ms on my laptop.